# listbox selected item as data source for new window

Tags: wpf, entity-framework-4

I have a WPF application I am working on that uses the Entity Framework 4.0 an Observable Collection and a few CollectionViewSources. On my form i have two text boxes i use to filter my data and then display it into a listbox based on what I have filtered it by. What I need to do is to have the user select an item from the listbox and hit a button ("Select") and the information is displayed wiht appropriate collections in a whole new window.
    So far I have:

```
Imports System.Data.Objects

Public Class SearchText

Private db As New CraftingProjectsEntities
Private ProjectsData As ProjectsCollection

Private ProjectViewSource As CollectionViewSource
Private MaterialsViewSource As CollectionViewSource
Private ColoringsViewSource As CollectionViewSource
Private DirectionsViewSource As CollectionViewSource
Private SpecialsViewSource As CollectionViewSource

Private WithEvents ProjectView As ListCollectionView
Private MaterialsView As BindingListCollectionView
Private ColoringsView As BindingListCollectionView
Private SpecialsView As BindingListCollectionView
Private DirectionsView As BindingListCollectionView

Private Sub SearchText_Loaded(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    Dim query = From r In db.Projects
                                  Where r.Materials.Count > 1
                             Select r

     Me.ProjectViewSource = CType(Me.FindResource("ProjectsViewSource"), CollectionViewSource)
    Me.DirectionsViewSource = CType(Me.FindResource("DirectionsViewSource"), CollectionViewSource)
    Me.ColoringsViewSource = CType(Me.FindResource("ColoringsViewSource"), CollectionViewSource)
    Me.SpecialsViewSource = CType(Me.FindResource("SpecialsViewSource"), CollectionViewSource)
    Me.MaterialsViewSource = CType(Me.FindResource("MaterialsViewSource"), CollectionViewSource)
    Me.ProjectViewSource.Source = Me.ProjectsData

    Me.ProjectView = CType(Me.ProjectViewSource.View, ListCollectionView)
    Me.DirectionsView = CType(Me.DirectionsViewSource.View, BindingListCollectionView)
    Me.ColoringsView = CType(Me.ColoringsViewSource.View, BindingListCollectionView)
    Me.MaterialsView = CType(Me.MaterialsViewSource.View, BindingListCollectionView)
    Me.SpecialsView = CType(Me.SpecialsViewSource.View, BindingListCollectionView)


    MyLists.ItemsSource = ProjectsData

End Sub 

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim query2 As ObjectQuery(Of Project) = Nothing
    Dim query = From p In db.Projects
                Select p

    If TextBox2.Text.Length > 1 And TextBox1.Text.Length > 1 Then

        query2 = query.Where(Function(p) p.Materials.Any(Function(m) m.Material1.ToLower().Contains(Me.TextBox1.Text)) And
                 p.Materials.Any(Function(m) m.Material1.ToLower().Contains(Me.TextBox2.Text)))

    ElseIf TextBox2.Text.Length < 1 And TextBox1.Text.Length > 1 Then

        query2 = query.Where(Function(p) p.Materials.Any(Function(m) m.Material1.ToLower().Contains(Me.TextBox1.Text)))

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("What are you looking for?")
        Return
    End If

    Me.ProjectsData = New ProjectsCollection(query2.ToList(), db)
    MyLists.ItemsSource = ProjectsData

  End Sub
                           **Works great through here... Below is where i get lost trying to get the selected item to the new window**
  Private Sub btnSelect_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnSelect.Click
    Dim mychoice As New MyChoice
    Dim selitem = Me.MyLists.SelectedItem
    mychoice.ProjectsData = (selitem)
    mychoice.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Any thoughts on how I could do this or where I could find an example showing the proper way of doing this would be extremely appreciated.  Thanks.
Adam
Sorry.... not using MVVM if this helps.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7498780/1069200) answers your question

Answer (score 1):

Make your model `Project` a parameter of the `MyChoice` window class.  Depending on whether it's required for the window, make `Project` a required or optional parameter of the `MyChoice` constructor.  Set it as the Data Context for your new window's Layout Root, set it as a property of the Window class itself, or put it in the View Model; whichever is appropriate.